# Stopping floating menu showing on MediaController android

Tags: android, menu, floating, mediacontroller

What do I override to stop these 3 dots from showing up on a mediacontroller? onPrepareOptionsMenu isn't being called. I've tried iterating through the view to see if there was something I could hide but found nothing.

[image]

In the logs I see this and I think it is causing this to be shown but see now way of affecting it.

```html
04-06 15:27:08.143: V/MediaPlayer(16605): constructor
04-06 15:27:08.143: V/MediaPlayer(16605): setListener
04-06 15:27:08.173: D/PhoneWindow(16605): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
04-06 15:27:08.173: D/PhoneWindow(16605): *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
04-06 15:27:08.173: D/PhoneWindow(16605): *FMB* installDecor call setFloatingMenuEnabled(true)
04-06 15:27:08.173: D/PhoneWindow(16605): *FMB* setFloatingMenuEnabled enable : true, mFloatingMenuBtn : null
```

Comment: Is this on a Samsung device?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes it is.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a Samsung-specific thing, as I can't find anything from your logcat in the Android source. It appears to be a child of the `DecorView` of the `PhoneWindow` that `MediaController` creates for itself, which is why you wouldn't find it by looking through the `MediaController`'s child `View`s. You could try using reflection to get the `View mDecor` field in the `MediaController`, search it, and remove the FMB. Or you might try using reflection to get access to the `setFloatingMenuEnabled()` method, and call it with `false`.